# MongoDB - count is deprecated

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm making a MongoDB query where i both need to loop through my results and count the len of the result to see if i'm being returned an empty result.

Here is what i tried:

```
Record = db.mycol.find({"datetimeraw": dt.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')})

RecordLen = Record.count()
print('LEN IS':RecordLen)

for x in Record:
    print(x)
```

This code works, but when i use it i get the following error: `DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead.` The problem is that i cannot use `count_documents()`, since it will return an integer and not a list of results that i can loop through; i would have to make two queries in this case: one to count and one to retrieve the results, and i would like to avoid that. Is there any way to do this or can i only use a depecrated function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB `.find()` will always return a cursor, which can either be empty `[]` or an array of documents/dicts `[{},{}]`.

As [.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/index.html) can be used in three ways :

```
/** 1. Queries all docs based on filter and then returns no.of docs matches with query */
db.collection.find( { queryFilter } ).count()

/** 2. Returns no.of docs */
db.collection.count()

/** 3. Returns a cursor `results` */ 
results = db.collection.find( { queryFilter } )
results.count()
```

So first two options are similar to [countdocuments()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/index.html#db-collection-countdocuments) and [estimateddocumentcount()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/index.html#db-collection-estimateddocumentcount) (returns a number) but as you wanted to return the documents and also get the count on cursor similar to [cursor.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/index.html) then you can do it in code by using `len()` method : `len(list(results))`.

Comment: len(list(results)) seems like a bad idea with a large query - it converts it to a full list of documents, which potentially uses a tonne of memory. But as OP points out, not being able to use Cursor.count sue to the deprecation means that it requires two requests if your want both the count and a results cursor.. seems like an odd decision to deprecate the feature.

Comment: @naught101: agreed `count` is deprecated for a reason, but `countdocuments` which is similar to count is the latest one to be used - if you only need `count` i.e; no.of docs! but OP needs to get both `documents+count(total no.of docs)`. So any how you need to convert `cursor` to `list` to access docs. So take the `list` into a variable and do `len()` on it. **Ex.** `records=list(results) RecordLen=len(records)`. I've aggregated entire syntax in one line in my answer! but my original intent is this. Hope it helps! I'm newbie to python feel free to suggest/edit.`Two queries/aggregation is heavy`

Comment: @naught101: So to put it simple, if you only need `count`, directly use `db.coll.countDocuments()` - that way you doesn't need to return any docs other than a number! But if you need docs then you anyhow will convert it to `list` So you don't need `cursor.count` function simply you can use `len()`-- maybe this is the reason why drivers deprecated `cursor.count()`!!

Comment: Not true. The Cursor is a generator. It allows you to load one document at a time in to memory, operate on it, and then garbage collect it, and move on to the next document. Creating a list loads all of the documents into memory at once. Depending on the use case, this could be a problem.